# how to return random upcase and downcase strings from a lowercase strings array

Tags: ruby

Is there an efficient way to return a string either in uppercase or in lowercase randomly? I don't want to use `upcase` or `downcase` inside an array as follows. Also Array will contain two names, lets say ["Cary", "Ursus"] and the ouput i want would be randomly one of these 4 outcomes. 1- My name is CARY or My name is cary or My name is URSUS or My name is ursus.

```
def random_case(name)
  name = ["jordan".upcase, "jordan".downcase]
  name.sample
end

puts "My name is #{random_case(name)}"
```

Answer (score 7):

What about this one? 0 for upcase, 1 for downcase

```
def random_case(name)
  rand(2).zero? ? name.upcase : name.downcase
end
```

`rand(2)` returns `0` or `1`.

If you want to take methods randomly from an array

```
def random_case(name)
  name.public_send([:upcase, :downcase].sample)
end
```

Multiple names as requested in comments

```
def random_case(*names)
  names.map { |name| rand(2).zero? ? name.upcase : name.downcase }
end
```

You can call this last one with

```
random_case("Ursus", "Cary")
```

Last request in comments

```
def random_case(*names)
  names.sample.public_send([:upcase, :downcase].sample)
end
```

Comment: the first one is part of the method name `zero?`, the latter is part of the syntax for ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot i knew ternary but newer heard of method .zero? ,  i am new to programming, one last question what if we have two name strings and want the same way one random string from each name. for example     name1 = "jordan"  name2 = "Ursus"  and i want random output out of 4 combination. #1- upcase jordan    #2- downcase jordan   #3-upcase ursus   #4 downcase Ursus

Comment: Good answer, but I think it would be strengthened by limiting it to #2.

Comment: @NasAh I provided a solution for your last comment

Comment: @CarySwoveland can you please explain a bit, which one would you prefer, what do you mean by #2

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to see only wheat, no chaff. My preference would be to limit it to `def random_case(*names)` with `public_send` in the body, but hey, that's just me. I'll delete my comments after the dust settles.

Comment: @Ursus one small issue with your last code as it is returning both names together randomly i only want one random name out of those two either uppercase or lower case at a time. Any help please

Comment: `names.sample.public_send([:upcase, :downcase].sample)`

Comment: The second form with `[:upcase, :downcase].sample` is great, but it'd be better if you created a constant for that array to avoid re-creating it each time this method is run.

Comment: Yes @tadman. That's the way I'd do it. But there is not context here. I hope the user can change it in his own code.

Comment: Nas, do you mean the array will always contain two names and you want to randomly chose one to upcase and then downcase the other? Regardless, you need to edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: Array will contain two names, lets say ["Cary", "Ursus"]  and the ouput i want would be randomly one of these 4 outcomes.  1- My name is CARY or My name is cary or My name is URSUS or My name is ursus.

Comment: I added that now

Comment: Nas, OK, but you need to edit your question and add that. It's fundamental to the question yet not all readers read all comments. Note that choosing one of those four outcomes randomly is equivalent to randomly upcasing or downcasing each of the two words.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have another option:

```
def random_case(*names)
  name = names.sample.downcase
  [true, false].sample ? name.upcase : name
end
```

So

```
10.times do
  p random_case('Kirk', 'Spock')
end
```